# Not receiving origin header for CORS request

Tags: cors, http-headers, cross-domain

I have an HTTP endpoint that is called via my website's SDK, from multiple other websites (`withCredentials` for my website). This is for single sign-on / authentication purposes.

Whenever I inspect a request manually, I always see the origin header included.

However, some small but significant portion of requests are sent without an origin header. I am unable to track down one of these requests that does not include the origin header, I only get notified of them hitting my server.

My understanding is that browsers will always include the origin header in CORS requests. Why do certain requests not include the header? Are they scripted / bot requests? Do some browsers not send origin headers?

If my endpoint allows credentials/origin, what should I do with these requests? Just ignore requests not containing the origin header? Should I update my SDK to also send the origin, instead of relying on the HTTP header?

Comment: Just ignore the requests that don’t contain the Origin header. If the endpoint’s purpose endpoint is to only be called from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, then in that case, browsers will always send the Origin header — so your endpoint will always work for the purpose you intend. At the very least, if a request doesn’t have an Origin header, then you don’t need to send back any Access-Control-Allow-\* headers in the response to that the request — because those will be just be ignored by all clients except browsers. And browsers are the only client that send the Origin header.

Comment: In other words, any requests that don’t include the Origin header are requests that you don’t need to care about for the endpoint case you’ve described — if that only purpose of the endpoint is for it to be called from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. As far why some do not include the header, it doesn’t matter where they’re actually coming from — whether it’s some crawler bot or whatever.

Comment: All current browsers send the Origin header for CORS requests. But not all requests browsers make are CORS requests. A CORS request is basically only made if the request is initiated from JavaScript code using the Fetch API or XHR or an Ajax method from a JavaScript. The browser otherwise doesn’t add the Origin header. So if a user opens the URL for your endpoint directly in a browser, no Origin header would be sent. Or if a crawler bot comes along, or somebody for some reason writes some code in a Python or whatever script that makes a request to the endpoint, then Origin header will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** You have no grounds to deny those request due to CORS (but could justifiably respond e.g. `400 Bad request` out of pragmatism).

CORS requires browsers to send `Origin` headers for requests transcending same-origin, because then the server can respond safely following protocol, if desired. You, as the server owner, only assist the browser if prompted.

The requests you see are likely from very old browsers (IE7 era), from direct request from browsers (URL typed in), or from bot-like scripts.

To deny them because they are not legitimate would muddy the distinction between CSRF protection and authentication. If you want to make separation of concerns very clear you should just respond.

If you want to save server resources it's justifiable to respond with a `400 Bad request`, because you describe only an authenticated use case.